# How to create donut chart in core-plot framework Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, ios-charts

I have searched out on google, not able to find any hint on core-plot donut chart example. Have no clue what so ever, how to do that. Neither there is example with dr chart framework.

Comment: I have created in donut chart with swift ios-chart, but not able to do in core-plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a donut chart in the *Plot Gallery* example app included with Core Plot. Use a pie chart plot and set both the `pieInnerRadius` and `pieRadius` to define the inner and outer limits of the donut ring.